# Derivation of gradient for non negative matrix factorization

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I am looking at a paper for non-negative matrix factorization and can't seem to figure out the derivation for the gradient. The function is as follows:

$f(W,H) = \frac{1}{2}||V-WH ||^2_F$

Where V is fixed.

The resulting gradients are:

$\nabla_W f(W,H) = (WH-V)H^T $

$\nabla_H f(W,H) = W^T(WH-V) $

I tried looking up rules in various reference manuals but never got anything solid. Even a hint / solid resource would be incredibly helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find it's often easiest to compute matrix-derivatives in [these terms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative#Definition), then translate to whatever the desired means of expressing the derivative is.  That is, I prefer to think of $\nabla_W f$ as a map from $\Bbb R^{m \times n}$ to the set of linear functionals on $\Bbb R^{m \times n}$.

We find that
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{\tr}{tr}
f(W + \delta W, H) = 
\frac 12 \tr[(V - (W + \delta W)H)(V - (W + \delta W)H)^T] =\\
\frac 12 \tr[[(V - WH)- \delta WH][(V - WH) - \delta WH]^T] =\\
f(W,H) + \tr[(WH - V)(\delta W H)^T] + o(\|\delta W\|) =\\
f(W,H) + \tr[[(WH - V)H^T](\delta W)^T] + o(\|\delta W\|)
$$
Thus, I would say that 
$$
[D_W f(W,H)](\delta W) = \tr[[(WH - V)H^T]^T(\delta W)]
$$
Translating this to your matrix calculus in which $\nabla_W$ should be a matrix, we find that
$$
\nabla _W f(W,H) = (WH - V)H^T
$$
as desired.

Comment: This is great! Thank you so much. Though I do have a problem understanding the transformation. Could you please point me to a resource or a more general example that would help me understand it? [Beyond wikipedia I mean :-) ]

Comment: Also, if a you could please explain what is happening between lines 2 and 3, it would clear things out a lot.

Answer (score 1):

For convenience, define the variable
$$\eqalign{
 M &= WH-V \cr
}$$
Write the function in terms of the double-dot (aka Frobenius) product and this new variable. In this form it's easy to find the differential
$$\eqalign{
 f &= \frac{1}{2}\,M:M \cr\cr
df &= M:dM \cr
   &= M:(dW\,H+W\,dH) \cr
   &= MH^T:dW + W^TM:dH \cr\cr
}$$
Setting $dH=0$ yields the gradient wrt $W$
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial f}{\partial W} &= MH^T \cr
}$$
while setting $dW=0$ yields the gradient wrt $H$
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial f}{\partial H} = W^TM \cr\cr
}$$
Double-dot products can be rearranged in a variety of ways, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
 AB:C &= A:CB^T \cr
   &= B:A^TC \cr
}$$ which follow from its equivalence to the trace $$A:B=\operatorname{tr}(A^TB)$$ and the cyclic properties of the trace.